# How check if a string has a space or it is end

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to check if one string has a space character or end string character.
Suppose to have this string:

```
var elem="tisof tisoff tiso"
```

I want to check if in this string elem there is the input "tiso". This element can be in the middle or in the head or at the end so my regex is:

```
var regex=new RegExp(/.*tiso\s/);
```

If I use the elem the test with regex is false because I need to put (\s or end string). Anyone can help me?

Comment: [`/\btiso\b/`](https://regex101.com/r/tX1qS5/1) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternation `(?:\s|$)`:

```
var regex= /.*tiso(?:\s|$)/;
```

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group meant to just group alternatives (it does not create any groups - remove `?:` if you need to reference the capture group value later), so `(?:\s|$)` will match either  a whitespace or the end of string.

**NOTE**: If you need to match a whole word `tiso`, you can use `/\btiso\b/` regex, where `\b` is a [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). The `\b` before `t` will require the letter to be preceded with a non-word character or the beginning of the string, and the last `\b` will require  a non-word character or the end of string after `o`.

Comment: If there is anything unlclear, please feel free to drop a comment.